# Can't name the route at post from submit

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to name the route in an `app.post()` (for example: `app.post("/today")`), but every time that I do it, the server gives an error:

> cannot submit / Post.

Please help me what I should do to fix it.

**index.js**

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static("public"));

let taskList = [];
let viewTaskList = ["Task 1","Task 2","Task 3","Task 4"];

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    
    res.render("index.ejs", {
        views: viewTaskList
    });  

});

app.post("/today", (req, res) => {
    
    let itemName = req.body.task;
    let button = req.body.add;
    button = true;
    if (button) {
        taskList.push(itemName);   
    }

    res.render("index.ejs", {
        task: taskList,
        views: viewTaskList
    }); 

});


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
  });
```

index.ejs:

```
<form action="/today" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="task" placeholder="New Item">
    <button type="submit" value="Add">+</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What is `kjh.kljhjhikl`?

Comment: Sorry I wrote it mistakenly in the question

Answer (score 0):

Try comment everything inside the post request and try to show `req.body` maybe you are not putting the correct data. If you don't see any wrong maybe it is the values you are trying to post as `itemName` and button.

```js
app.post("/today", (req, res) => {
    console.log("body", req.body)

    // let itemName = req.body.task;
    //let button = req.body.add;
    //button = true;
    //if (button) {
        //taskList.push(itemName);   
    //}

    //res.render("index.ejs", {
        //task: taskList,
        //views: viewTaskList
    //});
});
```

If you receive the same error you can add "/" to today like "/today/" or try to change the type submit to button

Comment: Hi Nauhl, I tried it but it still didn't work...